# where can I generate facebook badge code?

Tags: facebook

Few years ago, I could go into my profile and generate a badge with a link, something like:

```
...
http://badge.facebook.com/badge/...png
...
```

Now I can not find this functionality no matter what. Is there, maybe, some fresh tutorial or something on that topic?

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/badges/ still exists, but https://www.facebook.com/badges/profile.php only throws a 500 internal server error. Suppose you could report this as a broken feature via the Help section ... at least they might be able to tell you if that is still available, or was discontinued.

Comment: Hmmm, I did write them, but no answer for a several days now